# Apex if Condition

Tags: salesforce, apex

I get an error Condition expression must be of type Boolean.

```
for (Account acc: trigger.new)
    {
        if(acc.RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id  from RecordType WHERE sObjectType =    'Account' AND IsActive = True AND Name = 'Health Care' LIMIT 1].Id)
        {
            //some code 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(pos.RecordTypeId == [SELECT Id  from RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Account' AND IsActive = True AND Name = 'Health Care' LIMIT 1].Id)
```

Use double `==` instead as above.

Comment: Yes. That did solve my problem. Actually I have one more question.